# Why can you execute controller logic of another controller from a view (renderView) but not from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm converting an old asp application to asp.net MVC slowly. The legacy system executed everything out of a single driver page which had logic for what content to display based on the QueryString. For the meantime I want to have a controller that does the same thing so that I don't need to rework all of the links. It'd be great if I could call a main driver action which would direct me to the appropriate controller / action or direct me to an iframe action which just displays content from the original system.

However I'm finding that I don't seem to be able to create this logic from a controller. It seems that from the controller the best option available is redirectToAction but this method loses all of the request and form parameters that were passed in to the initial call.

On the other hand I'm finding that if I simply execute the logic in the view (bypassing the controller entirely) I'm able to call Html.RenderAction with the controller and action I want, not passing any additional parameters in and I'm able to retain, at least, the original parameters that were used in the calling of the driver page for later use in the logic of the new controller action. Then I just return the result back to the view.

It works and I'm going along with it for now but I'm wondering why this functionality isn't available where it'd make since to have it; The controller.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend creating a service layer and putting common logic there.  Then each controller can call that independently.

Comment: What logic are you recommending putting up in the service layer for the controllers to call?

Comment: If two different controllers need to run the same set of logic then that is usually a sign that that logic should be hoisted up to a service layer.  I can't really give you specifics because I have no idea what is in your solution but that is the basic idea.

Comment: There's no similar logic in this case. All links are to the same driver page from the legacy system and that page runs logic that determines what to display. So the idea is to not have to alter the links and instead replicate the driver page design. I guess I could just write a function that took in the currently supplied href and returned a href with the proper controller / action. That might be a good alternative to this.